How to build restful API using virtual threads
With the introduction of virtual threads since Java 21, it seems like it will become the future to use instead of the reactive model (ref. Do Java 21 virtual threads address the main reason to switch to reactive single-thread frameworks? ). I was wondering then what is the recommended way to build a restful API using virtual threads. Since Spring Boot 3.2, the virtual threads could be enabled by setting the relevant property (ref. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-6-virtual-threads), suppose there is no thread pining issue to consider, is it all that needs to do to build restful APIs by virtual threads?
spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true


Yes it is. Unless you want to do parallel processing internally as well (although @Async would work as well).

According to some researches reactive model remains most effective. Pros and cons of migrating from reactive model to virtual threads is discussed here.
